# Java JPG DCT coefficients alter by themselfs after I modify them

Tags: java, image, jpeg, steganography, dct

I have a program that changes the DCT coefficients of a JPG image.
This is the code that gives me the DCT coefficients

```
    public int[] quantizeBlock(double inputData[][], int code) {
    int outputData[] = new int[blockSize * blockSize];
    int i, j;
    int index;
    index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            // The second line results in significantly better compression.

            outputData[index] = (int) (Math.round(inputData[i][j]
                    * (((double[]) (Divisors[code]))[index])));
            // outputData[index] = (int)(((inputData[i][j] * (((double[])
            // (Divisors[code]))[index])) + 16384.5) -16384);
            index++;
        }
    }

    return outputData;
}
```

This is a DCT matrix before modifications

```
     -43 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     -8 1 2 -1 0 0 0 0 
     -1 -1 -1 1 0 0 0 0
     -2 1 0 -1 0 0 0 0
      6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     -2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
     -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is after the modifications

```
      -42 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
      -7 1 3 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
      -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
      -1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

After I save the image using image Buffer,I use the created image to get back the modified DCT from it but all I get is:

```
      -41 9 0 0 0 0 0 0
      -6 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
       0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've seen a question where the user using a library in IOS  did the same thing and had the same problem.Apparently the library recopressed the image and the hidden message was destroyed.

I don't know if this is the case for me.I use Image Buffer to create the image.

Comment: Have you tried writing the raw data to a jpeg format yourself? Irrelevant to the question, but relevant to the performance of your algorithm, but why don't you embed/extract from the coefficients in a zig-zag order?

Comment: This question has a poor description. You haven't laid out step-by-step, from the beginning to the end, how you embed your secret and save the image. A link to a hundred of lines of code, whose sole purpose is to load an image from a file and save it as a jpeg, isn't going to cut it. People won't even read that. As it currently stands, I suggest you look into the source code of the F5 algorithm (written in Java, alters DCT and saves to jpeg) to see how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things off the top that could be happening. The first is rounding errors. The JPEG process introduces small errors. All your values are one off. This could come from rounding.

The second is quantization. Your values may be quantized (divided). Your example does not indicate the compression stages that may be taking place in between your examples.

Comment: I used http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Performsajpegcompressionofanimage.htm for JPEG compression.This code as I undestand follows the compression steps

Comment: See if you find any variations that are greater than +/-1.

Comment: @EmilGrigore From your link, the `StandardUsage` says that a quality of 100 is almost the same as the original image. So you will suffer some compression.

Comment: user3344003     no,all my variations are in -1/1 range.

Comment: That sounds like rounding errors. JPEG requires essentially requires doing floating point operations on integers. This is normally done by shifting and using fixed point math. This still causes slight errors.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the process. I am making a new JPeg which is the compressed version of the current one. When compressing the current JPeg, I modify the DCT coefficients and then I go to Huffman encoding to make the new compressed Jpg. I really don't know why the coefficient are different and I really need to solve this

Comment: You do quantize your coefficients, don't you? Once the coefficients are quantized (lossy), the rest of the process should be lossless. Why don't you post your code?

Comment: Reti43         The code is pretty big.I posted the quntized code part.I modify the DCT right after this part before the Huffman Coding.This is the code I used http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Performsajpegcompressionofanimage.htm

Comment: Like I said in a comment above, the `StandardUsage` method in that code says that even a quality of 100 is not going to save the exact image.

Comment: As you all said,I think the problem is that there are some errors at the round up in the lossy compression.Can you give me some sugestions how I can remedy this problem ?Ireally need to finish this as soon as possible.Thank you all for you help !